# Was my answer deleted for the solution being too simple?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I'm a pretty new user and not very familiar with the policy of Stack Overflow, so I'm asking this question to better get into this.

I posted my first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249577/application-css-manifests-require-tree-is-working-but-requiring-individual-fil) and my answer was approved by the OP as it solved his problem.

Today I noticed having lost all my reputation and checked out the question page just to see my answer having been deleted by a moderator.

Yes, my answer was short and simple, but that is because so was the solution. The OP was simply having a typo in his code.

[image: My answer]

1. Is it so that a question with such a "silly" problem cannot be answered at all?
2. Can such a question be answered only by commenting it and therefore not at all by a user with too low reputation (me)?
3. If 1. or 2. applies, shouldn't the question be closed rather than an answer solving it?
4. Or was my answer just so poorly written that it deserved being deleted for that? Should I have added the original code with the typos corrected to have my answer meet the standards or something like that?

I will be glad to hear why my answer was deleted and how I should help the OP next time.

Comment: I can see why a mod may convert your answer to a comment and close the question but to delete without closing or converting makes it less useful for everyone (maybe because you have less than 50 rep it couldn't be converted to a comment) but if that's all the answer there is it should definitely be closed.

Comment: It will eventually be deleted if it's 0 score, if I'm not wrong, but not as early.

Comment: All your reputation are belong to us.

Comment: Highest rated typo related answer of all time now.

Comment: You lost some points on SO, but won a lot on Meta.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, where the points are so irrelevant that they don't even get awarded.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert You do realize that there are no points on meta.SO, right?

Comment: @Joe Only if it also meets several other criteria, such as having no answers or positive-vote answers.

Comment: I like the fact that you now have the "Nice answer" and "Enlightened" badges - *seemingly* without ever having given an answer at all! Maybe you find comfort the badges being more durable than reputation...

Answer (score 108, accepted):

No, it wasn't deleted because the solution was too simple. Your answer was flagged as "Not an Answer," probably because it looked like you were just pointing out a typo. It may not have been immediately clear to the flagger or the moderator that the typo was actually the root of the problem.  I've undeleted your answer.

The question has now been closed as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**." It will *probably* eventually be deleted, so don't get too attached to those reputation points. ;)

Comment: I would add that it would be helpful to add to the answer a *bit* more text, such as "Your code works fine, except you have a typo".  That makes it more clear to moderators (and others reviewing the post) that it is a complete answer, and not just commentary on the question (often questions contain irrelevant typos).

Comment: That's a nice way of saying that `You will die eventually after few days but for now live peacefully` :) ... LOL (Disclaimer: with `you` I don't point to anyone specific but rather set of all human beings)

Comment: Even though it ultimately wouldn't have mattered for this particular case, I wonder if the more trigger-happy among those with mod privileges would be a little more thorough if there were rep penalties for making bad calls. Then again, metaposts such as this seem fairly effective for sorting these situations out.

Comment: @Joe While your statement is valid, moderators should not simply delete something so causally and hardly look into it. They should at least look at the question, and see if the answer was indeed the solution.

Comment: @Joe: To put that another way:  If you're going to post a clear and concise answer, top it up with a couple paragraphs of rambly fluff so nobody accidentally mistakes it for commentary on the original question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This hardly warranted looking in to. It's an answer pointing out a typo to a typo question. It's going to be deleted anyway.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, but I mean generally. Just things you should do at a minimum to ensure people will not miss-flag or assume before testing and checking.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand why moderators don't get the full context when looking at flags in the first place. What possible reason is there to *not* show the question when you're judging the quality of an answer?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Because 99.9% of the time we don't need it and it would just be clutter in the mod queue.

Comment: Although [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25250045/revisions) does show you undeleted the answer, now that the question has been deleted, the answer shows up as "deleted by Bohemian♦ yesterday". A glitch, surely, but is it something to just ignore, or something that could in other circumstances cause actual problems?

Comment: @hvd I don't think that's a glitch. That's part of the revision history of the answer. Bohemian deleted it, then I undeleted it later. (You can hover over the text "occurred yesterday" to get the time stamps to see in what order actions were taken.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I understand that the revision history part is correct, but as I noted, now that the question has been deleted, when looking at the answer (without the revision history), the answer shows up as deleted by Bohemian, separately from the fact that the whole question has been deleted. [Here's a screenshot to clarify what I mean.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ejJ.png)

Comment: @hvd Oh, I see. I was just looking at the revision. Yes, that is a glitch, but I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: Alright, will ignore it then, thanks. I wasn't sure if it might sometimes let answers stay deleted even after they've supposedly been undeleted. Thinking about it now, I can take a guess as to what might be happening: Should the answer be visible? The question was deleted, so no. If the answer shouldn't be visible, and as a "deleted by" action in the revision history, the page shows "deleted by" based on the revision history. If that's what's happening, then sure, that can't cause actual issues.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Personally I think any glitch should be worried about since it may be a symptom of a larger underlying problem (eg undeleted answers may show as deleted in other places too). I'm not sure what the appropriate way to bug report things to stack is though...

Comment: @Chris You can post a question here on Meta and tag it "bug".

Comment: If you wait a month to delete it, will the reputation stay?

Comment: @TylerH The reputation from a deleted post will stay if the post has a score of 3 or higher and it's been visible for 60 days or more.

Answer (score 12):

Aside from [Bill's reply](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268533/1190388), I would also add that instead of answering questions having a typographical error, flag them for the same reason.

There is nothing wrong with answering a silly question. But, since [SO] is a stack of questions which are applicable to wider audiences, a little typo by any user will not actually help anyone apart from the OP themselves.

Yes, such a question **should** be closed (and eventually deleted), you answered it in less than half an hour of it being posted. Give the community a little bit of time before proper action can be taken on such questions. As I mentioned before, next time onwards, you can help closing such questions quicker by raising flags all around :)

Comment: Unfortunately, "simple typographical error" questions never seem to get closed in a timely fashion.  If the OP hadn't answered it, someone else would have.

Comment: If you're going to flag it, at least leave a comment saying their problem was a typo and how to fix it. I know that I've spent plenty of time in my programming career debugging problems that were caused by a stray (or missing) comma; one letter off somewhere; messed up whitespace; etc. Be nice, let them know what they did wrong

Comment: You should do both (answer and vtc/flag).  Otherwise the typo might not get fixed - and you really shouldn't vtc/flag until you're sure it is really the problem. Lots of times the typo is added in the entering of the question and isn't the problem.

Comment: The "simple typographic error" close reason is worded in such a way that it implies the question has been answered and accepted, but the solution is too trivial. So definitely go ahead and post an answer.

Comment: I just want to point out that questions about stupid things like typos  can actually end up being helpful. For instance it might be a common typo that causes a not-so-obvious error message.